# Почему не хочет экранироваться текст в php?

Tags: php

Почему не хочет экранироваться текст в php таким образом

```
echo <<<TEXT .............. TEXT;
```

Вроде всё правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При объявлении нужно убрать отступы перед закрывающей меткой.

```
<?php
$var = <<<TEXT

TEXT;
?>
```

> It is very important to note that the
> line with the closing identifier must
> contain no other characters, except
> possibly a semicolon (;). That means
> especially that the identifier may not
> be indented, and there may not be any
> spaces or tabs before or after the
> semicolon.

Comment: Трандец, а почему так?

Comment: Того требует стандарт.

Comment: Спасибо! Сам был догнал и офигел стакого стандарта если чесно,наверно час мучался пока методом тыка разобрался

Comment: Пожалуйста. Отметьте как правильный ответ.

Comment: Никто не виноват (в том числе стандарт) в том, что вы его не знаете, а делаете методом тыка.

Comment: Отметил))

Comment: Да,я согласен,но просто мне показалось что немножко не стардартный стандарт))

Comment: Посоветуйте хорошую книгу по php